# Scroll to element always resets view until page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a small single page website with 4 sections. First is a single image landing page then 3 "about" sections below, that should all be set at the full viewport.

I'm trying to use some javascript to be able to scroll smoothly to each section on a button click, but when I click the button, the javascript event triggers and the page quickly scroll to the correct section but then back to the starting position.

I've tried multiple versions of JS to get this working but I'm thinking it might be a something else causing the defect.

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVdTQWASliE).

And trying to make the bottom text sections the same as the first.

```js
document.getElementById('readMore').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('section-a').scrollIntoView();
});
```

```css
/* Zero out padding/margin - sets 0 for all CSS styling */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style: 17px;
  color: #926239;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#section-a,
#section-b,
#section-c {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

#showcase h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

#section-a,
#section-c {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #926239;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#section-b {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#seeMore {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>firstName lastName</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>firstName lastName</h1>
    <h2>Job Title</h2>
    <div>
      <a href="" id="readMore" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="section-a">
    <div></div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur iusto saepe eligendi rem neque esse dolor? Sunt sint illum, numquam reiciendis eum provident cum corporis perspiciatis architecto! Quisquam tenetur quia facilis natus, sed delectus eligendi
      corrupti quae inventore enim omnis rem provident ipsum sit quo, impedit libero sequi laboriosam quas nihil iste cumque corporis illum? Similique dicta perferendis, doloremque consequuntur ab molestiae magnam illo qui numquam nostrum ad quod, enim,
      molestias libero. Quam ad nisi officiis quis ipsam necessitatibus fuga hic, architecto sed, quae harum dicta incidunt culpa veniam reprehenderit sunt ratione vitae molestiae iste sapiente, impedit consequuntur cum perspiciatis?
    </p>
  </section>
  <section id="section-b">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur iusto saepe eligendi rem neque esse dolor? Sunt sint illum, numquam reiciendis eum provident cum corporis perspiciatis architecto! Quisquam tenetur quia facilis natus, sed delectus eligendi
      corrupti quae inventore enim omnis rem provident ipsum sit quo, impedit libero sequi laboriosam quas nihil iste cumque corporis illum? Similique dicta perferendis, doloremque consequuntur ab molestiae magnam illo qui numquam nostrum ad quod, enim,
      molestias libero. Quam ad nisi officiis quis ipsam necessitatibus fuga hic, architecto sed, quae harum dicta incidunt culpa veniam reprehenderit sunt ratione vitae molestiae iste sapiente, impedit consequuntur cum perspiciatis?
    </p>
  </section>
  <section id="section-c">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur iusto saepe eligendi rem neque esse dolor? Sunt sint illum, numquam reiciendis eum provident cum corporis perspiciatis architecto! Quisquam tenetur quia facilis natus, sed delectus eligendi
      corrupti quae inventore enim omnis rem provident ipsum sit quo, impedit libero sequi laboriosam quas nihil iste cumque corporis illum? Similique dicta perferendis, doloremque consequuntur ab molestiae magnam illo qui numquam nostrum ad quod, enim,
      molestias libero. Quam ad nisi officiis quis ipsam necessitatibus fuga hic, architecto sed, quae harum dicta incidunt culpa veniam reprehenderit sunt ratione vitae molestiae iste sapiente, impedit consequuntur cum perspiciatis?
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
<script src="./public/js/javascript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Once I've understood how this works I'd have buttons in each section that move you up and down the sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prevent the default behavior of the link. So you can do something like that:

```
document
      .getElementById('readMore')
      .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        document.getElementById('section-a').scrollIntoView()
      })
```

But in this way its kind a unnecessary because you get the same behavior with just a normal link.

Comment: Thanks! This does work, and as you say, is just like a normal link. The intended effect was for the page to smoothly scroll to the next section/element.

Comment: Read this about smooth scrolling: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp